# Writing rows of numbers to csv file, if they match the header

Tags: python, list, csv, dataframe

I have 32 tab-separated text-files of the following format (showing 3):

Filename: 90-4-0

```
gene_ID Genes Frag TPM Func
    1   23    34   43 some_function1
    2   43    66   11 some_function2
    3   54    22   88 some_function3
```

Filename: 150-2-1

```
gene_ID Genes Frag TPM Func
    1   1    34   5    some_function1
    6   22    2   11   some_function6
    3   9     1   54   some_function3
```

Filename: 90-2-0

```
gene_ID Genes Frag TPM Func
    9   54    21   4   some_function9
    11   2    6   143  some_function11
    3   99    44   8   some_function3
```

and so forth for about 2000 rows for every file. The filenames of the 32 files are of the format "SampleID-Timepoint-Status", all 3 descriptors seperated by "-".

- SampleID can be any two or three digit number.
- Timepoint is a number from 1-4
- Status is either 0 or 1

Now, I want my final output to look like this (pref in csv format):

```
Sample_ID Timepoint Status gene_ID1 gene_ID2 gene_ID3 gene_ID6 gene_ID9 gene_ID11 *etc*.
90        4         0      43       11       88       0        0         0
150       2         1      5        0        54       11       0         0
90        2         0      0        0        8        0        4         143
*etc*
```

The number for all the gene_IDs come from the "TPM" column in the files. "Genes", "Frag" and "Func" can be disregarded. I just showed them for the sake of formatting. 
The final file will roughly be of the dimension 32x2000. Keep in mind, that the number of gene_IDs for each file can vary. For Sample_IDs that do not have values for some of the gene_IDs, it should say "0" (as illustrated in the table).

Now, I know how to fetch the file IDs, timepoints and status from the file-names, and I know how to get everything from the 32 files into a dictionary. I have tried just about any combination with putting everything into a dictionary. I also tried to put every 32 Sample_IDs into 32 separate lists with their respective values, but I can't figure how to connect them with the "gene_IDs." If I put them all in a list of the format:

```
Sample_ID Timepoint Status TPM_value ... TPM_value_n
```

How do i relate the "TPM" values to the "gene_IDs"?

I'm open to all suggestions or helping code if you have the time.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pd.concat`, you can merge rows without having to fill all the null values.

```py
row_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Sample_id':[90],'Timepoint':[4],'Status':0,'gene_1':[43],'gene_3':[88],'gene_6':[56]})
row_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Sample_id':[150],'Timepoint':[2],'Status':1,'gene_2':[53],'gene_3':[18],'gene_5':[16]})

df = pd.concat([row_1,row_2],axis=0)
```

Will return:

```
    Sample_id  Status  Timepoint  gene_1  gene_2  gene_3  gene_5  gene_6
0         90       0          4    43.0     NaN      88     NaN    56.0
0        150       1          2     NaN    53.0      18    16.0     NaN
```

And then replace NaNs

```py
df = df.replace(np.NaN,0)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I never knew about this. How do I connect the Sample_ID, Timepoint and Status to the rest then? Can i just put them in a list in the start? Does the dataframe have to contain only dictionaries?

Comment: @Alex yes you can just specify they are columns on each row. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, I just got it! Thank you very much!
When i wanna write it to a csv file, how do you suggest I do that, with this format?

Comment: @Alex pandas has `to_csv` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: I see, clever! Last thing, does panda have som kind of append function? For when I want to append values from a dictionary, to the dataframe?

Comment: You can add a column by doing `df[NEW_COLUMN_NAME] = COLUMN`

ex: `df[gene_9000] = [4,5,0 ... 67]`